# Record with required keys and string index

Tags: typescript

This is what I want

```
type Report = {
  branches: number; // should be required
  functions: number; // should be required
  lines: number; // should be required
  statements: number; // should be required
};

const report: Report = {
  branches: 10,
  functions: 19,
  lines: 54,
  statements: 67,
}
```

but I can’t do this

```
const items = Object.keys(report).map(key => report[key])
```

typescript (version 4.3.5) shows the following error on `report[key]`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Report'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Report'.ts(7053)

So I try this

```
export type Report = {
  [key: string]: number;
  branches: number;
  functions: number;
  lines: number;
  statements: number;
};
```

but now it allows something like

```
const withFoo: Report = {
  branches: 25.3,
  imABug: 45, // should not be allowed!
  functions: 20.1,
  lines: 70.01, 
  statements: 45,
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cant map it"?

Comment: ^ I revised the question

Comment: ^ I revised the question

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't `Object.keys(foo).map()` it"? [This works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYHsBOwoF4oG8BQUoCMkBDAOwGMALCAZwC4oSBXAW3wiQG4oB6bqaigkYAbACYFoSCAEdGASymjcUAGaNywOQhJ0GLNpx58BQsRKhTZCiErzC5JGvSat2XXv0EjxbCzPmKytTARMAQzBAkwLouBu7GXma+lgE22AC+HNjYZNrBqggI9HCIKOhYyoSklE5QAIwADAA0ymoaWjr0dQCcLXYOtQCsACx9-CFhEVG6AGwA7C3p2QDy+ABWEGTAAHQA1hAg1AAUKoUAlNvMRGBHEMLoAHxQuToIwhDbwggA5rfCZ2cgA)?

Comment: Seems to work just fine in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKxKzgXjgbwCg44AjKAQwDsBjAC2AGcAuOKgVwFtTgoBuOAHpBcRnQjsANgBMyqKMACO7AJYLpxOADN2tGCohUWbLj35CRYiTLlwFytcA0lJKqk1YduvAcNHipWR47JVV1TUYYChhgTmAqGGMvM19LAJtg+zCnQgBfPkJCGkNIuAB3FRg6ADEICFYMLHg8IhJyanoPOAAmAFYAOgBmABpNHT0DI1ZugAZ+gEZRlzcugHY5mcW4CKiYuITjABZe0dzC4qN4UgooXDgAeVIAK2AaGH6Aa2BERgAKCqqtQgAEp+pwKGBfpVYrgAHxwAAG4LAKFkABJ8NDOLkEcCCkA).

Comment: @Etheryte yes. I'm not sure if OP is referring to "No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Report'" when trying to read value `foo[item]`

Comment: ...in which case, `Object.entries(foo).map(([key,value])=>...)` would sidestep the type mismatch

Comment: ^ I’ll add the error report to the question

Comment: The error report of what code? Afaik, the code you show us won't produce this error. Without knowing the code that produces it, and knowing what you want to achieve it's hard to give suggestions

Comment: typescript version 4.3.5 – strict

Comment: This line: `Object.keys(foo).map()` won't produce the error. Likely what is inside of `map(...)`. Can you show that and tell us what you want to achieve with this line of code?

Comment: ^ Updated question per feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are creating an array of strings with `Object.keys()` and trying to map to `Report` object, which I feel is just bad implementation.

Why don't you try this for iterating over the properties instead:

```typscript
type Report = {
  branches: number; // should be required
  functions: number; // should be required
  lines: number; // should be required
  statements: number; // should be required
};

const foo: Report = {
  branches: 10,
  functions: 19,
  lines: 54,
  statements: 67,
}


Object.entries(foo).map(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value));
```

Comment: Note that you could [get more keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYHsBOwoF4oG8BQUoCMkBDAOwGMALCAZwC4oSBXAW3wiQG4oB6bqaigkYAbACYFoSCAEdGASymjcUAGaNywOQhJ0GLNpx58BQsRKhTZCiErzC5JGvSat2XXv0EjxbCzPmKytTARMAQzBAkwLouBu7GXma+lgE22AC+HNjYoJBQAMqMkEhwiCjosPDIqABkWEEIEQByEADuAApICMWg9ABMAMwALBnZZNrBqggI9IXFpdUVOHiEpJROUACMAAwANMpqGlo69JsAnPt2DhsArEOX-CFhEVG6AGwA7A-UjRAtHV0eiB+sNRthxjpUPgiEh6AtyhgVNNsgB5fAAKwgZGAADpIsAkHIaAAKaFIACUOOYRDAxOJEGE5PQAD4oBCfsIIDjhAgAOb0xnkjhAA) than present in the original type

Comment: Interesting – https://caniuse.com/object-entries is a bit worse than https://caniuse.com/?search=object.keys but not by much – I wonder if my setup would auto-polyfill anyway